# Segmentation fault on using Eigen::MatrixXf as function return type

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen3

I'm trying to return a value of type `Eigen::MatrixXf`, but this results into a segmentation fault. Trying to debug, I've found that if return type is something else like a `float` or `int` with a corresponding return value in the function, the function runs successfully. I have tried the diagnose the problem from the Eigen documentation from [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), but without any help.

```
MatrixXf& create_V_matrix(cv::Mat H) {
    // Gather V matrix
    MatrixXf v11 = get_vij_matrix(H, 0, 0);
    MatrixXf v12 = get_vij_matrix(H, 0, 1);
    MatrixXf v22 = get_vij_matrix(H, 1, 1);
    MatrixXf V;
    V << v12.transpose(),
        (v11-v12).transpose();
    return V;
}

MatrixXf get_vij_matrix(cv::Mat H, int i, int j) {
    // Create v matrix at i and j
    MatrixXf vij;
    vij <<  H.at<float>(0, i)*H.at<float>(0, j),
            H.at<float>(0, 1)*H.at<float>(1, j) +
            H.at<float>(1, i)*H.at<float>(0, j),
            H.at<float>(1, i)*H.at<float>(1, j),
            H.at<float>(2, i)*H.at<float>(0, j) +
            H.at<float>(0, i)*H.at<float>(2, j),
            H.at<float>(2, i)*H.at<float>(1, j) +
            H.at<float>(1, i)*H.at<float>(2, j),
            H.at<float>(2, i)*H.at<float>(2, j);
    return vij;
}
```

This results in a `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` when the `create_V_matrix(cv::Mat H`)
is called.

Comment: In addition, you are passing everything by value, which is illegal in Eigen, and they stay this explicitly, read: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicPassingByValue.html

Comment: It seg faults even though `get_vij_matrix` is not called.

Comment: @selyunin There is no `Eigen::` type matrix that is being passed as value too.

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `et_vij_matrix`, you need to set the size of the `MatrixXf` `vij` before using `operator <<` to assign values. Otherwise, the allocated storage for `vij` has a zero size and your assignments are going to be out of bounds. I counted 6 values you're trying to assign, so `vij.resize(1,6)`, `vij.resize(2,3)`, `vij.resize(3,2)`, or `vij.resize(6,1)` is required before the assignments.

Likewise, your matrix `V` is not resized before assigning the values from `v11` & `v12`.

Finally, as noted by [PeterT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041557/segmentation-fault-on-using-eigenmatrixxf-as-function-return-type/58046993#comment102497512_58041557), you're `create_V_matrix` returns a `MatrixXf&` reference to a local variable, which is undefined behavior. While it might work, it is not required to. See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) for a great explanation. If you're worried about the copy, you can and should rely on RVO/copy elision to remove the pointless copy.

Comment: This worked like a charm and instead of local variable referencing, I am now passing an `Eigen::MatrixXf` by reference to the function `get_vij_matrix`. Also, if you've worked with `OpenCV`, is it better to use `Eigen::` library for matrix operations or the `cv::Mat` class in OpenCV? This is when I'm dealing with an application with `OpenCV`.

Comment: Sorry, OpenCV is not my specialty. It probably depends on how you define “better” though.